# How do I validate that a Radio Button is selected upon a click event?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to help and I'm definitely out of my element on this assignment. I'm by no means a programmer but sometimes can manipulate pre-existing code.

I have a HTML web part form loaded on a SharePoint front end. The form has basic features to fill out, one of which is a Radio button feature.

I'm unsure of the proper html or better yet where to even place it (which function) or even if I can place it in a pre-existing function.

I've done quite a bit of googling around and have tried this method. I'm sure that the syntax maybe off and perhaps that's why it does nothing and I'm able to proceed when I "check-in" Upon click of that button "Check-in" is when I'd like the validation to check and see if a radio button is selected. By default there is no default selected (yes I know, but don't tell me why it's bad practice just doing my job).

```
if(document.form1.btn-group[0].checked == true) {
    alert("Please select On-Site or Remote Surveillance Type");
}
```

The pre-existing code is very lengthy and again I'm no developer so perhaps I placed the code in the wrong place. If anyone has the time to assist this would be greatly appreciated and I think it would be very beneficial.

```
function checkInSupplier(){
if (!onloadCheckin){
    //Save PRS/SRA data
    ia.loadScreen.displayCover(true, 'Verifing PRS/SRA Data');
    ia.loadScreen.changeProgress({load: true});
    updateTokenData();

    //Save parts data
    ia.loadScreen.displayCover(true, 'Verifing Part Data');
    ia.loadScreen.changeProgress({load: true});
    updatePartsData();

    //Save progression date data
    ia.loadScreen.displayCover(true, 'Verifing Progression Data Data');
    ia.loadScreen.changeProgress({load: true});
    updateProgressionDateData();

    //Save notes data
    ia.loadScreen.displayCover(true, 'Verifing Note Data');
    ia.loadScreen.changeProgress({load: true});
    updateNotesData();

    //Save mandatory contacts data
    ia.loadScreen.displayCover(true, 'Verifing Mandatory Contacts Data');
    ia.loadScreen.changeProgress({load: true});
    updateMandatoryContactData();

    //Save additional contacts data
    ia.loadScreen.displayCover(true, 'Verifing Additional Contacts Data');
    ia.loadScreen.changeProgress({load: true});
    updateAdditionalContactData();

if(document.form1.btn-group[0].checked == true) {
alert("Please select On-Site or Remote Surveillance Type");
```

}
    }

Comment: Don't post your full code. It is difficult to perceive. Please, create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Alexander ...edited.sorry =/

Comment: Please, share HTML snippet that contains the radio button (or buttons).